# How to use carousel with bootstrap 5.0.2 in React js

Tags: reactjs, carousel, bootstrap-5, web-frontend

I am using bootstrap@version 5.0.2 in react js. I am trying to add carousel but for this bootstrap version did not get, so I tried to use carousel bootstrap@version 5.3.2 but it is not working.
I also tried bootstrap@version 4.0.0 carosual and it's working but my other pages css create conflict.

My index.html file CDNs -

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

My Home.js file -

```
import './Home.css';

useEffect(() => {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000
        })
    }, []);

return (
<div id="carouselExampleControls" className="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                            <div className="carousel-inner">
                                <div className="carousel-item active">
                                    <div className="banner-main-block">
                                        <div className="banner-text-block">
                                            <div className="banner-block-items-content banner-text-block-items-content">
                                                <h2>Levi's</h2>
                                                <p>Levi's, the iconic American denim brand, Levi's offers timeless fashion that never lacks.</p>
                                                <Link className='homepageLink' to="#" onClick={(e) => handleSearch(e, "levis")}>SEE MORE</Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="banner-image-block">
                                            <div className="banner-block-items-content">
                                                <div className="">
                                                    <img src="images/homepage/banner.jpg" className="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="carousel-inner">
                                <div className="carousel-item">
                                    <div className="banner-main-block">
                                        <div className="banner-text-block">
                                            <div className="banner-block-items-content banner-text-block-items-content">
                                                <h2>Levi's 2</h2>
                                                <p>Levi's, the iconic American denim brand, Levi's offers timeless fashion that never lacks.</p>
                                                <Link className='homepageLink' to="#" onClick={(e) => handleSearch(e, "levis")}>SEE MORE</Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="banner-image-block">
                                            <div className="banner-block-items-content">
                                                <div className="">
                                                    <img src="images/homepage/banner.jpg" className="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="carousel-inner">
                                <div className="carousel-item">
                                    <div className="banner-main-block">
                                        <div className="banner-text-block">
                                            <div className="banner-block-items-content banner-text-block-items-content">
                                                <h2>Levi's 3</h2>
                                                <p>Levi's, the iconic American denim brand, Levi's offers timeless fashion that never lacks.</p>
                                                <Link className='homepageLink' to="#" onClick={(e) => handleSearch(e, "levis")}>SEE MORE</Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="banner-image-block">
                                            <div className="banner-block-items-content">
                                                <div className="">
                                                    <img src="images/homepage/banner.jpg" className="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
)
```

I am trying to add carousel but for this bootstrap version did not get, so I tried to use carousel bootstrap@version 5.3.2 but it is not working.
I also tried bootstrap@version 4.0.0 carosual and it's working but my other pages css create conflict.

So please let me know how we can use crosual slider with bootstrap 5.0.2. Help me !